# I do not understand the following javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to align my side nav to the left even on mobile, at the moment it just displays below the top nav when in mobile sizes (smaller than 768px). I have tried everything that I know of, so i decided that the problem must lie in my JavaScript, seeing as this is not one of my strong points. I can understand it a bit, because i know Java. So I would like to know what the following code does...

```
$(function() {
    function responsiveView() {
        var wSize = $(window).width();
        if (wSize <= 768) {
            $('#container').addClass('sidebar-close');
            $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
        }

        if (wSize > 768) {
            $('#container').removeClass('sidebar-close');
            $('#sidebar > ul').show();
        }
    $(window).on('load', responsiveView);
    $(window).on('resize', responsiveView);
});
```

Comment: On load and pageresize `responsiveView` function call and check if width size lessthan/equal 768 then add class `sidebar-close` and hide `ul` else show ul and remove class `sidebar-close`.

Comment: what about reading the jquery docs yourself? They're very well written, full of samples, and very understandable

Comment: Try CSS instead @media - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don't need javascript for this, use CSS media queries instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Will be like the equivalent of this in terms of java structures. but it is using jquery.

> **Note**: alot of the functions are lying in the jquery library so I won't show them below. $ = jquery

```
public Class $
{
    private void responsiveView()
    {
        int wSize = $.window().width();
        if(wSize <= 768) 
        {
            window.container.addClass('sidebar-close');//it retrieves a reference to the element and adds the className used by CSS
            $('#sidebar > ul').hide();//replaces each ul in the element with the id of sidebar. sorry didn't want to think about the java equivalent
        }

        if (wSize > 768) 
        {
            window.container.removeClass('sidebar-close');
            $('#sidebar > ul').show();//shows all ul within element with id of sidebar
        }
//this codes runs after function/methods are compiled
    $.window.on('load', responsiveView);//sets the function/method to run on window load event
    $.window.on('resize', responsiveView);//sets the function/method to run on window's resize event
    }
}
```

hope that helps.
keep in mind the addclass will allow the element to have multiple classes. so if your css is assigned to the class it will apply both stylings